# Angular + NodeJS: Read Files From Folder With Promises (fs.fileRead and fs.readdir)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-promise, fs

I'm trying to read files from a folder using NodeJS and Angular. I'm able to iterate through the folder and access the files data, no problems here.
My main issue i that i'm unable to pass the result (array of names) to the $scope and show it to the user - the array is always empty. I think this is related with fs asynchronous behaviour.

I'm doing the following:

**Angular Service:**

```
myApp.service('peopleService', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {

    var self = this;
    this.people = [];

    var peopleService = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(folderPath, function(err, files) {
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                var obj;
                fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);

                    var person = { name: obj.obituary.name, ... };

                    self.people.push(person);
                });
            });
        });

        resolve(self.people);
    }).then(function(people) {
        return people;
    });

    return peopleService;
}]);
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$http', 'peopleService', function($scope, $http, peopleService) {

    $scope.people = [];

    peopleService.then(function(people) {
        $scope.people = people;
        console.log($scope.people); //empty array (Array[0])
    });

}]);
```

**Angular Page:**

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="person in people">
        {{person.name}}
    </a>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you'are mixing nodeJS code with angularJS code?

the problem is `resolve(self.people)` is executed before `readdir` and `readFile` callbacks are executed because they are asynchronous, so you have to make sure that `resolve(self.people)` will executed after  `readdir` and `readFile` callbacks :

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(folderPath, function(err, files) {
            var count = 0;
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                var obj;
                fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);

                    var person = { name: obj.obituary.name, ... };

                    self.people.push(person);

                    count++;
                    if(count === files.length){
                       resolve(self.people);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    }).then(function(people) {
        return people;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @bougarfaoui. I'm developing a desktop app using angularjs and electron. Since i need to access the file system, i have to use node js within angular. Is there an alternative? Regarding my question, your solution solved my issue.

Comment: @Ricky oh sorry I forgot Electron, there is no problem.  Do not forget to mark my solution as a correct answer, thnx :).